# Is it possible to start an application when a background notification is received in a locked android or ios?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, push-notification

I wish to send a background notification to an iphone or android locked phone. The notification will start the application. Is this possible, as I have been told by someone that it can't be done as a message dialog pops up which requires the user to press OK first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS cannot launch third-party applications without the user's approval. I can't say what Android will do.